# Stuttery 1080p playback on decent system

Tags: media, playback, 1080p, coreavc

We have a media center system that was recently built. It works well for all types of content, however it has issues with 1080p content. 720p plays fine.

I have tried VLC, ffdshow and finally, CoreAVC. CoreAVC plays the best however it still eventually loses sync due to stutter - this does not happen on other systems with the same file.

Specs:
Asrock 4core-2dual sata

PCI Express ATI 2400 HD

1.5GB DDR 2100

Intel Pentium E5300

120GB Maxtor Diamondmax PATA

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)?

In any case, I never succeeded to get pretty smooth 1080p only using the CPU (no matter what).

So, I highly recommend to get some new NVidia card (there are even cheep M210 in the range of 30$) with [VDPAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) support. You will be stunned how good it works to offload the decoding to the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a case of your graphics card just not having the muscle to do it. Keep in mind that 1080p video has over twice the number of pixels as 720p. This means that it requires quite a lot of graphics processing power to display, and your card unfortunately does not look like it can keep up.

Comment: I would agree, would it not be for the fact that others use the same card and still get 1080p :(

Comment: Hm. Interesting. Are they running single-core CPUs too?